# MariaDB/MySQL update field with last updated in single query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Given tables like:

Table A:

```sql
id | tokens
1  |  2
2  |  0
3  |  0
4  | 999
```

Table B:

```sql
Id | from | to | amount | status
1  |  1   | 2  |  2     | wait
2  |  1   | 3  |  2     | wait
3  |  4   | 1  |  2     | wait
```

How to update the token field in Table A from B's rows in a single UPDATE?

I tried

```sql
UPDATE B, A
SET A.tokens=A.tokens-B.amount,
    B.status="ok"
WHERE A.id=B.from AND B.status="wait"
```

The result is
Table A:

```sql
id | tokens
1  |  0
2  |  0
3  |  0
4  | 999
```

Table B:

```sql
Id | from | to | amount | status
1  |  1   | 2  |  2     | ok
2  |  1   | 3  |  2     | ok
3  |  4   | 1  |  2     | ok
```

It seems like the update is performed but the amount of tokens are wrong. 
What I am expecting is:

Table A:

```sql
id | tokens
1  |  0
2  |  0
3  |  0
4  | 997
```

Only the deduction part is tested above. I don't know how to perform the add part at the same time as well. Furthermore, would it be possible to disallow any further update once amount is going to be negative? 
In a complete solution, it is expecting:

If row 3 in Table B is performed in between row 1 and 2

Table A:

```sql
id | tokens
1  |  0
2  |  2
3  |  2
4  | 997
```

Or if row 3 of Table B is performed after row 1 and 2, because either row 1 or row 2 will be forbidden for negative tokens of 1 in Table A.
Table A:

```sql
id | tokens
1  |  2
2  |  2/0
3  |  0/2
4  | 997
```

Can someone help?

### Update

With the following, I can perform the add part. 
Table A:

```sql
id | tokens
1  |  4
2  |  0
3  |  0
4  | 999
```

Table B:

```sql
Id | from | to | amount | status
1  |  1   | 2  |  2     | wait
2  |  1   | 3  |  2     | wait
3  |  4   | 1  |  2     | wait
```

```sql
UPDATE table_A, table_B
SET table_A.toekns = CASE 
    WHEN table_A.id = table_B.from THEN table_A.tokens- table_B.amount 
    WHEN table_A.id = table_B.to THEN table_A.tokens + table_B.amount
    END,
    table_B.status = "ok"
WHERE ( table_A.id = table_B.from OR table_A.id = table_B.to ) AND table_B.status = "wait"
```

However, the result is

Table A:

```sql
id | tokens
1  |  4         //Why is 4 not 2??
2  |  2
3  |  2
4  | 997
```

Table B:

```sql
Id | from | to | amount | status
1  |  1   | 2  |  2     | ok
2  |  1   | 3  |  2     | ok
3  |  4   | 1  |  2     | ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a query like this:

```
UPDATE tablea ta
left join tableb tb ON ta.id=tb.`from`
left join ( SELECT `from` ,SUM(amount) as amount from tableb GROUP by `from`) tc ON ta.id=tc.`from`
SET ta.tokens=ta.tokens-tc.amount,
    tb.status="ok"
WHERE tb.status="wait"
```

Comment: I am sorry that this provide the same result as the one I was using. ``1.tokens`` in tablea deducted only 2 not 4

Comment: @l l - try the next. i have changed it

Comment: thanks. The updated version is working for subtraction part. Unfortunately the addition part and the non-negative checking part are not accomplished.